# "Resource was acquired but never released" error with parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
I am trying to log in and sign up using my application and found the above error.
Following is my code of main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (ParseAnonymousUtils.isLinked(ParseUser.getCurrentUser())) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginSignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Following is my code of LoginSigupActivity

```
public class LoginSignupActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button loginButton;
Button signupButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_signup);
loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_launcherSignIn);
    signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_launcherSignUp);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
    }
    });
    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSignupActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Folloing is my login activity class code

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button loginButton;

String txtUsername;
String txtPassword;
EditText password;
EditText username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtUsername = username.getText().toString();
            txtPassword = password.getText().toString();

            ParseUser.logInInBackground(txtUsername, txtPassword, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Welcome.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This user does not exist! Please Sign up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Following is my signup activity code

```
public class SignUpActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button signupButton;

String txtUsername;
String txtPassword;
EditText password;
EditText username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    signupButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtUsername = username.getText().toString();
            txtPassword = password.getText().toString();
            if(txtUsername.equals("") && txtPassword.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please complete the signup form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(txtUsername);
                user.setPassword(txtPassword);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if(e==null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signed up successfully...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Signup Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

And following is my Parse connector class code

```
public class ParseConnecter extends MultiDexApplication{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "zblr0TmjldGaV2xSl5******aFhe6DW78FjA2u", "9Ys6j7uY68115********2pvo5Ldfia");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);


}


}
```

Comment: please provide your logcat logs

Comment: its too long how can i share it here?

Comment: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)

Comment: 01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okio.GzipSource.<init>(GzipSource.java:57)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:478)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:668)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)

Comment: 01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)

Comment: 01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:795)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:760)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at

Comment: com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:667)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:651)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.j.a(SourceFile:209)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:263)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at

Comment: com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)

Comment: 01-25 16:31:18.108 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.at.run(SourceFile:142)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at

Comment: com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.closeGuardOpen(SourceFile:324)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SourceFile:292)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.KitKatPlatformOpenSSLSocketImplAdapter.startHandshake(SourceFile:318)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at

Comment: You should edit your question and add the stack trace there

Comment: com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.a(SourceFile:258)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SourceFile:557)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:171)
01-25 16:31:18.112 1668-1672/? E/StrictMode:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)

Comment: how can i edit my question?

Comment: @jacksonChengalai i have posted log file in the following answer